# Ошибка (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Делаю программу, которая распознаёт лица на фотографии.

Вот мой код:

```
import cv2
image_path = 'D:\JustAProject\pic.jpg'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor= 1.1,
    minNeighbors= 5,
    minSize=(10, 10)
)
faces_detected = "Лиц обнаружено: " + format(len(faces))
print(faces_detected)
# Рисуем квадраты вокруг лиц
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
viewImage(image,faces_detected)
def viewImage(image, name_of_window):
    cv2.namedWindow(name_of_window, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(name_of_window, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Получил такую ошибку и не понимаю, как её исправить:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/PyCharm/projects/venv/Lib/test5.py", line 10, in 
>       minSize=(10, 10)
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите полный путь к `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'/path/to/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

пример:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3\envs\ml\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

чтобы проверить наличие файла:

```
import os

fname = r'C:\...\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'

print(os.path.isfile(fname))
```

Comment: ничего не вышло. выводит ту же самую ошибку

Comment: @Desertdevelober, вы указали путь к этому файлу на __вашем__ компьютере?

Comment: да,конечно. нашел этот файл в проводнике, а затем скопировал его путь из "свойств"

Comment: так... есть еще какие-нибудь предложения?

Comment: Стоп, а что за r перед путем файла?

Comment: a... всё. добавил r и теперь все работает. Спасибо большое

Comment: @Desertdevelober, [raw strings in Python](https://www.codevscolor.com/python-raw-string/)